# How do I install WebRTC in my own server (Windows Server)

Tags: webrtc

I just hear about WebRTC and want to do some test with this potential technology.
Could you guys please guide me how to download and install WebRTC in my server (using win 32).
And what I should consider about for codec...etc...

Thank in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "install WebRTC in my server"? Do you want to install an MCU?

Answer (score 1):

What about the getting started guide from the official reference documentation?https://webrtc.org/getting-started/overview

Comment: Updated link

https://webrtc.org/getting-started/overview

Comment: Thanks @ArunjithRS, I fixed the link in my answer.